# Determine which wcf endpoint is being used on the server

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-endpoint

I have a wcf service thats exposing a service using two endpoints. One endpoint is used for web service calls while the other is using rest.

Is there a way to determine from which endpoint the server functions are being called?

Comment: one problem im encountering is that soap and rest handle erros differently. To report an error in rest you need to send a bad request as a response, and this causes an unhanded exception in soap.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, contrary to what I thought - it's actually pretty easy to find out what endpoint the service was called on. In your service method, add these lines of code:

```
OperationContext oc = OperationContext.Current;

if(oc != null)
{
    string wasCalledOn = oc.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress.Uri.ToString();
}
```

But as I said : I would use this very wisely and "defensively" - don't start changing service behavior based on what endpoint your method was called on - that would be very bad design!

I tried this with several SOAP endpoints - not 100% sure how REST will be handled (but most likely the same or very similarly) - try it out!

But for logging, this should work just fine!

Comment: Instead of `.ToString()` I've been using `.Segments.Last()`.

Answer (score 2):

Lifted from the blog entry [here](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/25/get-the-service-endpoint-address-a-client-is-accessing-in-wcf/):

> You just need to look at the
>   LocalAddress on the Channel of the
>   current Operation Context in the
>   method:
>
> ```
> OperationContext.Current.Channel.LocalAddress
> ```